# Prove that $\gcd(2^a-1,2^b-1)=2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that $\gcd(2^a-1,2^b-1)=2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$

Hints-

$1$. Use Euclids Lemma

$2$. $2^a=2^{a\%c}\mod (2^c)-1$

$3$. If $a=q\cdot b+c$ then $2^a=(2^c)^q\cdot 2^r$

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: More generalized version: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: @lab, I think the more general question is also answered (just not asked) at the question I cited.